# UITableViewCell's custom pic freeze when i scroll it up or down

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I insert custom UIButton on UITableViewCells and when i click it UIButton's pic change to checkmark and when i touch it again it turn to unchecked pic. When i scroll UITableView then i cant make them unchecked , simply cannot change pics. It is like pics getting freeze when i scroll it up. my code is below.

```
-(void)insertButtonOnCellTw:(UITableView *)tableView IndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath Cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {



UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(actionButtonOnCellTw:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
button.tag=indexPath.row;
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgEmptyCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(285.0f, 20.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f);
[cell addSubview:button];
```

}

```
-(void)actionButtonOnCellTw :(id)sender
{
 UIButton *but=(UIButton*)sender;
 NSNumber *intIndexPathRow=[NSNumber numberWithInt:but.tag];
      if([masivCheckedTwCells containsObject:intIndexPathRow])
      {

        [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgEmptyCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [masivCheckedTwCells removeObject:intIndexPathRow];
    }
    else

    {
        [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [masivCheckedTwCells addObject:intIndexPathRow];
    }


}
```

I can solve it like after scrolling clean all checkmarked cells and put them again in "for" condition but there is any other and more clear way?

Comment: Where are you calling insertButtonOnCellTw? Where is masivCheckedTwCells and are you sure you're initializing it?

Comment: @Rob I am calling insertButtonOnCellTw in  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  and yes i initialize NSMutableArray in viewDidLoad method. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and want to share for if anyone will stuck in same problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method is reuse every cell over and over again when i scroll it up, so it doesn't create new one but reuse it. 
With this codes i clean it before reuse it.

```
NSArray *subviews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:cell.contentView.subviews];
for (UILabel *subview in subviews)
{
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
for (UIButton *subview in subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
subviews = nil;
```

And my last mistake was i was adding buttons on cell like this.`[cell addSubview:button];` but it is better add it to contentView like this `[cell.contentView addSubview:button];`

Comment: While this might solve your problem, it is definitely not the best solution, and IMO, the worst solution. If you weren't aware that cells are re-used when you scroll, I strongly recommend you look into how to properly use UITableViews, and how subclassing UITableViewCell might be the best thing you can do. Your solution of adding all subviews, and then removing them and adding them again, is VERY inefficient.

Comment: Also, your second loop does nothing, since the first loop took out ALL subviews (whether or not they're labels, buttons or whatever). If you don't understand why, I also suggest you read up before continuing. I'm not trying to be condescending, and in fact you might be learning right now... which is great. But if you're planning on submitting to the app store, you should become more familiar with everything before taking on a big project.

Comment: @Rob It is ok, no problem.  I did that as subclass of UITableView cell and it works fine. If you will post logical answer i can mark it as an answer.